# Error #2035 URL not found - file path configuration

Tags: actionscript-3

I try to open a `swf` from another `swf`. They are on the same folder. Here is the code block I am trying to get the file.

```
var newRequest:URLRequest;      
var path:String = "mahmut"+".swf";
newRequest = new URLRequest(path);
newLoader = new Loader;
newLoader.load(newRequest);
newLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeFn);
newLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, camaluriFn);

function camaluriFn(e:IOErrorEvent)
{
    trace("Error: " + String(e));
}
```

---

and trace throws `Error #2035: URL Not Found. URL: app:/mahmut.swf`

So how can I give right path and it can open display successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't matter where those files are, what matters is from where they are loaded. In your case all local paths are from the app root no matter what. If you swf are in folder "myswfs" then the right path is not just "mahmut"+".swf" but "myswf/smahmut.swf".

Comment: I will check it asap. Moving one level up seems logical and I remember I read something about that.

Comment: Not working at all.

`Error #2035: URL Not Found. URL: app:/mywfs/mahmut.swf`